# Getting list of windows in Tk and destroying specific ones (R)

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of windows in Tk, and destroy specific ones. I am working in R using the tcltk interface, and am calling a function written by someone else a long time ago (that I cannot edit) which is producing additional windows that I don't want.

From the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk/versions/3.5.1/topics/TkWidgets), it seems that new `Toplevel` windows are children of `.TkRoot` by default. I know that Python has a `winfo_children` method,  which I was thinking of trying to call on `.TkRoot` but I don't think that method is implemented in the tcltk library. I tried using `tcl("winfo", "children", .TkRoot)` but I am getting an error: `[tcl] bad window path name "{}"` (I'm not familiar with actual tcl, so I'm probably messing this command up).

Additionally, if there is a way to call `winfo children`, what's the best way to process the result to identify specific windows and then destroy them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the R sources](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/tcltk/R/Tk.R), I see that you should be doing:

```
tkwinfo("children", .TkRoot)
```

Except that I think that won't work either, as `.TkRoot` doesn't have a corresponding widget on the Tk side of things. Instead, use the string consisting of a single period (`.`) as the root of the search; that's the name for the initial window on the Tcl side of things. And I suspect that you'll just get back a raw Tcl list of basic Tk widget names without the R wrapping as I just can't see where that conversion is applied…

---

Be aware that the results may include widgets that you don't expect, and that you need to call it on every window recursively if you want to find everything.

Comment: Thanks! As a side question, is there a reason that they didn't include it in the docs (or did I just not see it)? Is it just because, as they say in the comments above the docs "it's rarely used"?

Comment: Ah, I did find it, but it's grayed out for some reason.